# Statsmodels Kalman Filter: simple equivalent to pykalman set up (partly answered)

Tags: kalman-filter, statsmodels

Following some examples on Chad Fulton's blog and in statsmodels' tests,
I have tried to come up with an equivalent of a pykalman implementation.

The original question was deemed unclear and was requested to be edited.

In the meanwhile, I familiarised myself a bit more with Kalman fiters and partially answered the question.

The below is thus a mix bag of a reformulated question and a less-than-ideal answer.

First, a back-ground of the specific example.

What we are attempting here is sometimes called "Sensor fusion". We 
attempt to observe the same *hidden* state from several noisy sources 
and try to rebuild it.

Mathematically and with some common notation in the Kalman litterature, the
problem is stated as follow:

1. State propagation

   we make no prediction here. We just observe a scalar quantity
   and so, if my understanding is correct, the below is intended 
   to say that the best prediction we can make is the previous 
   observation:
   \alpha_{t} = 1 \alpha_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t}
   where:

   - \alphat_{t} is the hidden state at time t
   - \epsilon_{t} ~ N(0, H)
   - H: Covariance matrix of state
2. Observation

   We have several sensors, all noisy, observing the
   same single state:
   y_{t} = Z_{t} \alpha_{t} + R_t  \eta_{t}

   - z_t{} = column vector of 1s with dimension the number of
     observations.
   - \eta_{t} ~ N(0,Q)
   - where Q is the observation covariance matrix

Now for the code.
In order to give a workable example as requested by the diligent editors of *Cross Validated*, I need a few preliminaries.

## Create a hidden state to be observed

For no special reason, we pick a Geometric Brownian Motion.

```
import pykalman
import statsmodels as sm
import statsmodels.tsa
import statsmodels.tsa.statespace
import statsmodels.tsa.statespace.mlemodel
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pendulum as pdl


def brownian_motion(T = 1, N = 100, mu = 0.1, sigma = 0.1, S0 = 20):
    dt = float(T)/N
    t = np.linspace(0, T, N)
    W = np.random.standard_normal(size = N)
    W = np.cumsum(W)*np.sqrt(dt) # standard brownian motion
    X = (mu-0.5*sigma**2)*t + sigma*W
    S = S0*np.exp(X) # geometric brownian motion
    return S
# strftime is to get rid of the nanosecond issue between pendulum 
# and pandas (taken from Stackoverflow som
dates = pd.date_range(pdl.today().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z"), periods=365, freq='d')
T = (dates.max()-dates.min()).days / 365
N = dates.size
start_value = 100
y = pd.Series(brownian_motion(T, N, sigma=0.1, S0=start_value), index=dates)
```

## Simulate observations with noise

```
nb_obs = 8
stdevs = np.arange(nb_obs)*2+2

dobs = {}
for i in range(nb_obs):
    dobs[i]=y+np.random.normal(0,stdevs[i], y.shape[0])
dbm_obs={'BM': y, 'obs': obs}
brownian_and_obs = pd.concat([y,obs],axis=1)
brownian_and_obs.columns = ['BM']+list(map(lambda s: 'obs'+str(s), range(nb_obs)))
```

## Two implementations of the Kalman filter

```
nb_srcs = 2 #nb_obs
states_initial = brownian_and_obs.filter(regex='obs.*',axis=1).iloc[0,:nb_srcs].values
states_all =brownian_and_obs.filter(regex='obs.*',axis=1).iloc[:,:nb_srcs].values

#
# pykalman
#
kf_pyk = pykalman.KalmanFilter(transition_matrices=[1.],

                                   observation_matrices=np.ones(nb_srcs).reshape(nb_srcs,1),

                                   initial_state_mean=np.mean(states_initial),

                                   initial_state_covariance=[1.],

                                   observation_covariance=np.eye(nb_srcs))



states_kfpk, _ = kf_pyk.filter(states_all)
states_kfpk = states_kfpk.reshape(states_kfpk.shape[0])
states_kfpk = pd.Series(states_kfpk,index=y.index)


#
# State model
#

mod_current = sm.tsa.statespace.mlemodel.MLEModel(states_all, k_states=1,initialization='stationary', k_posdef=1)

# y_{t} = Zt αt+ dt + εt

# Z : design (k_endog×k_states×nobs)

# d : obs_intercept (k_endog×nobs)

# H : obs_cov (k_endog×k_endog×nobs)

mod_current['design'] = np.ones(nb_srcs).reshape(nb_srcs,1,1)

mod_current['obs_cov'] = 100*np.eye(nb_srcs)



# αt = Tt α{t−1}+ct+Rt ηt

# T : transition (k_states×k_states×nobs)

# c : state_intercept (k_states×nobs)

# R : selection (k_states×k_posdef×nobs)

# Q : state_cov (k_posdef×k_posdef×nobs)

#mod_current['transition'] = np.ones(1) GOT AN ERROR WITH THIS UNCOMMENTED

# mod_current['state_intercept'] = np.zeros(a.shape[0]).reshape(1,a.shape[0]) WORKS BUT USELESS

mod_current['selection'] =np.ones(1)#.reshape(1,a.shape[0])#np.ones(1)

mod_current['state_cov'] = [10000]  # Variance set high initially if unknown

#mod_current.initialize_known(1, [[0.02]])

#mod_current['state_intercept'] = [[0]]#np.r_[controls[1:], np.nan][None,:]

res=mod_current.filter(states_initial)

states_kfsm = res.filtered_state
states_kfsm = pd.Series(states_kfsm[0],index=y.index)
```

## Visual results

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,10))
estimates = pd.concat([y,states_kfsm, states_kfpk],axis=1)
estimates.columns=['BM',  'KalmanSM', 'KalmanPyK']
sns.lineplot(data = estimates.loc(axis=1)['BM','KalmanSM'],dashes=False)
sns.scatterplot(data=brownian_and_obs.filter(regex='obs.*',axis=1).iloc[:,:nb_srcs]);
```

[image: Two observations (markers), Kalman estimate (orange line) and true (hidden) state (blue line)]
[image: Comparison of the two Kalman filters]

As said, I believe I partly answered my original question: 
the pykalman and 
the statsmodels implementation seem to yield similar results.

Now, it has raised others, which I list in order to turn this post into a question:

- I cannot un-comment the state transition in the statsmodels version. It yields an error
  I am not sure why.
- the Kalman seems sometimes far away (see February 2020 for example). 
  Besides, increasing the number of sources increases the standard deviation
  of the estimate and I was under the impression that the algorithm has the       potential not to degrade when more noisy sources are added. 
  Is that a correct implementation of the problem described above ?

Comment: your code isn't reproducible, but I find it odd that in the first example you're setting the 'obs_cov' to `np.eye(nb_srcs_current)` while in the second example you're setting the observation matrices to the same thing. We also might be able to say more if you $\LaTeX$ up your model

Comment: Hi Taylor, the intention was to have a transition of the form:
d y_t = d  \alpha_t  an. d d \alpha_t = d W_t where d W_t is a nb_src_current brownian motion. So a very basic model actually. The pykalman seems to be a ok job at filtering the sources when I look at the result.

Comment: looking at the two curves from the plot above, KalmanPyK seems to be less volatile than KalmanSM. The peak and trough of KalmanSM are definitely more extreme than KalmanPyK.